# Why does adding folder access for a user to a SharePoint folder extend access to a child folder with unique permissions

Tags: sharepoint

I'm using SharePoint 365 and working with a document library. Within I have a folder named Contracts. Within that folder I have numerous child folders - i.e. Contract 1; Contract 2; etc. On each of the child folders I stopped inheriting permissions so that I can grant access to each to appropriate users. But today, from the parent folder I selected the meatball icon and selected Manage Access and added a user. But even though each of the child folders was set to Unique permissions, they all inherited the user I added to the parent folder.

I repeated the same exercise from the parent folder using the Advanced permissions screen where I noticed there is an option "*Share everything in this folder, even items with unique permissions*". When I unchecked that option the child folders with unique permissions did not inherit the new user.

So it appears the option *Share everything in this folder, even items with unique permissions* is checked by default. Is there a way to change the default behavior of this option to not be checked?